# Shifting bit values

Tags: java

I have recently started learning java of my own back and I am having trouble with one part in particular. Today I read up on shifting bit values and I was wondering if what I am doing is correct?

I want to shift a value to the right by 16 bits and then clear the upper 24 bits by anding the value with an 8-bit mask of ones. Here is a segment of my code:

```
int shift(){
    point = point >> 16; //shifts the value to the right by 16 bits
    point = point & 0xFF; //clear the upper 24 bits
    return point;
  }
```

Is this correct? Am I using this technique correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: *"Is this correct?*" - You can easily check this!

Comment: I have no idea how I can check this, I literally am a very beginner!

Comment: @user2817587 That will be a good exercise to find a way to check if it's correct.

Comment: In future, please _EXPERIMENT_ before posting here.  You could have easily verified this yourself just by executing the code in a testcase.  If you have not yet learned about unit testing, please stop now and research JUnit.

Comment: It is not correct. For example, `point` is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

> > Yes.
> >     *some content to fill out the 30 characters minimum length*

OK, looks like that joke is not well-received, I was anticipating people to like this satyrical answer. Oh well, apparently people in SO are more serious than I thought.

Well, like others have mentioned, you can actually check it yourself!

As you have written in your code comments, you are already doing it right to convert your comment (human understanding) into code (machine understanding).

How do I know that you're correct? Well, you can check the online resources:

1. For [bit manipulation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)
2. Or just [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

So far your code seems to match your intention, after consulting those resources.

But, you say, that's theoretical, how do I know *empirically* that my answer is correct?

Well, you can do this method:

1. Build some sample test cases.
   For this case you can use hexadecimal number so that you can easily confirm it (because you can see each bit).
   For example: try `0xFFFFFFFF`, `0x80000000`, `0xC0C0C0C0`.
2. Find the correct answer *manually*.
   In this case, try shifting the bit yourself (using pen and paper)
   For `0xFFFFFFFF`, which is a 32-bit number with all 1's, when you shift 16 bits to the right you will get `0x0000FFFF`, which is a 32-bit number with 1's only at the last 16 bits.
   Then you do and AND operation with `0xFF`, which is a 32-bit number with 1's only at the last 8 bits. This will again give you `0xFF`, since only at the last 8 bits both numbers have bit 1.
   Repeat for other examples. You should get `0x00` and `0xC0` for the other example.
3. Run your code on those input.
   To run your code, you can use something called Java compiler (it's usually called javac in most systems).
   If you really are a beginner, you can try online compiler like [this](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php)
   Just put your code there and run (with Input/Output (I/O) management, explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2853/Java-Basics-Input-and-Output))
4. Compare your output with the program output.
   Usually, this alone will give you confidence that your code is correct.
   But sometimes there are tricky cases which make the code incorrect even though it's correct for some small examples. Fortunately we already checked the logic using theoretical answer above.

So I hope that helps!

Comment: Please do not fill out to the minimum with garbage.  You could expand your answer a little and explain how the OP could have checked this him/herself.

Comment: Wow, I can actually get *Peer pressure* badge using this kind of answer! I've been trying so far with unrelated answer, but not so much response. Apparently utilizing people's tendency to be a justice police is a better approach. Too bad I've already fixed my answer. Will try next time. >:)

Comment: Sorry if you were offended. SO is (still) a valuable resource but in the 5 years I've been a member, the signal-to-noise ratio has kept decreasing, and is approaching 0dB.

Comment: @JimGarrison: No I wasn't offended. I should thank you for your input, indeed. =) I've updated the content with even more detailed response. I hope this will help OP in understanding C++. Sorry that my previous comment seems harsh, I was simply amazed.

Comment: That's the reason why I like Stackoverflow so much. You can celebrate your humor BUT must always be respectful to anybody else. I like your answer - especially the edits.

Answer (score 0):

First let me welcome you to Java. Good choice!

About your question: If this is correct or not depends on what you expect.

But first of all, when learning Java you should do two things:

- Get a development environment like Eclipse.
- Learn how to write litte test routines with Junit. Here's a [JUnit Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html)

I've taken your code and embedded it in a test routine to see what actually happens:

```
public class Stackoverflow extends TestCase {
    @Test
    public final void test() throws IOException {
        testNprint(1234);
        testNprint(-1234);
        testNprint(0);
        testNprint(255);
        testNprint(256);
        testNprint(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        testNprint(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
       }

    private void testNprint(int point) {
        System.out.printf("int: %1$d (0x%1$X) -> shifted: %2$d (0x%2$X)\n",
            point, shift(point));
    }

    private int shift(int point) {
        point = point >> 16; //shifts the value to the right by 16 bits
        point = point & 0xFF; //clear the upper 24 bits
        return point;
    }
}
```

And here's the result. Now you can answer your question: Are the numbers as expected?

```
int: 1234 (0x4D2) -> shifted: 0 (0x0)
int: -1234 (0xFFFFFB2E) -> shifted: 255 (0xFF)
int: 0 (0x0) -> shifted: 0 (0x0)
int: 255 (0xFF) -> shifted: 0 (0x0)
int: 256 (0x100) -> shifted: 0 (0x0)
int: 2147483647 (0x7FFFFFFF) -> shifted: 255 (0xFF)
int: -2147483648 (0x80000000) -> shifted: 0 (0x0)
```

BTW: I guess the result is not as you've expected it :-) For the reason find out about the difference of `>>` and `>>>`.